# Convert string to DateTime to get Month short form

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this date in a string:

```
var dateString = "Saturday, September 16th";
```

What I am trying to do is get the short form of the month...in this case it would be Sept.

I've tried to convert it to a DateTime like so:

```
var newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I get this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Anybody know how I can get the short form of the month from the string?

Comment: `var shortMonth = "Sept";` is the best I can give you without more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string and format clearly don't match. That's why you get the exception.

You *can* use `dddd, MMMM dd'th'` and since your string doesn't have year part, it would be parse it as `2017` as year (and also because of 2017's 16th september is saturday).

```
var newDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Saturday, September 16th",
                                  "dddd, MMMM dd'th'", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But there is no custom date format that supply `Sept` as a result. It's [abbreviated month genitive name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthgenitivenames) or [abbreviated month name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthnames) return `Sep` as a result.

You *don't* have too much option other than generating it's full name with [`MMMM` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-mmmm-custom-format-specifier) and keep it's first 4 character with [`string.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring) method.

```
newDate.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(0, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your dates are in an inconsistent format, coupled with the fact that you want to get back non-standard abbreviation, I recommend just creating a function to serve as a kind of lookup table, like this:

```
private string GetMonthAbbr(string date)
{
    string[] longMonths = new string[] {"january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"};
    string[] shortMonths = new string[] {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

    for (int i=0;i<longMonths.Length;i++)
    {
        if (date.ToLower().Contains(" " + longMonths[i] + " "))
        {
            return shortMonths[i];
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

You can change `shortMonths` to contain whatever abbreviations you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something more like this:

```
var dateString = "Saturday, September 16, 2017";
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
string dateFormat = "MMM";
DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dt);
```

Then when you want to display the month you can call:

```
dt.ToString(dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: There is _no_ custom forhat that generates `Sept` as a result. And this string is _not_ the same string OP mentioned.

Comment: As I understand, the DateTime will be parsed to the current year if it is not specified. You are correct, there is not a month format that will generate "Sept" so if he wants to use DateTime, the only abbreviation available is "Sep". Otherwise he could just use a string literal for "Sept".